# Why can't I print an ARG with echo in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Specifying `ARG` in a `Dockerfile` even allows me to change the image tag with `docker build --build-arg`. Why doesn't it work as argument to `echo`?:

```
ARG VAR0
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN echo $VAR0
```

results in

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile-test --build-arg=ARG0="Hello!" --no-cache=true .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  19.97kB
Step 1/3 : ARG VAR0
Step 2/3 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> cd6d8154f1e1
Step 3/3 : RUN echo $VAR0
 ---> Running in 9724e22b51cc

Removing intermediate container 9724e22b51cc
 ---> 9f6369d2de17
[Warning] One or more build-args [ARG0] were not consumed
Successfully built 9f6369d2de17
```

(where I expect `Hello!` to be printed to console for the third step) whereas

```
ARG VAR0
FROM ubuntu:$VAR0
echo "Hello Docker!"
```

even allows to make the Ubuntu version configurable at build-time.

Comment: FWIW this works if the arg is called `var0` and if it's defined after the `FROM`.  Possibly some restrictions around capitalisation?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thank you very much for the hint. I can confirm your findings. `FROM` seems to reset the list of `ARG`s which at least allows it to both make the image tag a build var and allow further build args to be used in the Dockerfile - you just need to know it in case it's the intended behaviour (might be a bug as well).

Comment: That is correct. ARG is build-time argument, and will be passed on and consumed by the environment it hits. That means it will be passed on to the container refered to in the FROM statement, and consumed by that container, not existing (or being blank).

Comment: Should be defined *after* `FROM`